# returning an object by using a string in Java

Tags: java

I'm a bit stumped by this as I am still pretty new to Java.

Here is my issue:

I need to return an object by using a string to pass it to another object. Ie, I want to pass a string to the function (`getObject` in this case) and then compare it to an `ArrayList` of unit objects by using their `getCode` function.

What I have so far:

```
private Unit getUnitObject(String unit1Code) {
  for (int i = 0; i < units.size(); i++) {
    Unit currUnit = units.get(i);
    String unitCode = currUnit.getUnitCode();

    if (unit1Code == unitCode) {
      Unit selectedUnit = currUnit;
      return selectedUnit;
    } 
  }
}
```

It gives me an error - "this method must return a result of type unit"
I tried moving the return out of the for loop and still had no success?
Can I do it this way?

Comment: Please, don't compare Strings with `==`.. I thought this might be the first day without this `==` vs `equals` question :_(

Comment: Now for your question, you must return something if the `if` doesn't satisfy.

Comment: Never actually knew about the equals() function. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that if you don't find a match then you don't return anything.  Try this:

```
private Unit getUnitObject(String unit1Code) {
    for (int i = 0; i < units.size(); i++) {
        Unit currUnit = units.get(i);
        String unitCode = currUnit.getUnitCode();

        if (unit1Code.equals(unitCode)) {
             return currUnit;
        } 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Notice that I'm comparing String objects using `.equals()` as well.  You may want to return something better than `null` if nothing matches too.

Comment: @user2792920 No problem. :)  I cleaned up the code a little bit with my last edit since you can simply return `currUnit`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only return something when your if-statement comes true, but you need to return also something when it is false. It is good practive to only have one return-statement in a class.
Create a variable of the return type at the beginning (instantiated with null or a standard value) and change this variable based on your conditions.
In the end return that variable.

```
  private Unit getUnitObject(String unit1Code) {
    Unit selectedUnit = null;
       for (int i = 0; i < units.size(); i++) {
       Unit currUnit = units.get(i);
       String unitCode = currUnit.getUnitCode();


        if (unit1Code == unitCode) {
          selectedUnit = currUnit;

           } 
         }
       return  selectedUnit;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private Unit getUnitObject(String unit1Code) {
    Unit selectedUnit = new Unit();
    for (int i = 0; i < units.size(); i++) {
    Unit currUnit = units.get(i);
    String unitCode = currUnit.getUnitCode();

     if (unit1Code.compareTo(unitCode)) {
      selectedUnit = currUnit;

        } 
      }
       return selectedUnit;
    }
```

You have to always return a Unit object, not only the the uni1Code is equals to UnitCode.
Thus, you create a variable in the begining of the method and make the assigment if the if is true, and return in the end. It will return empty Unit or the currentUnit..

Answer (score 0):

With this configuration I hope it will work

```
 private Unit getUnitObject(String unit1Code) {
        Unit selectedUnit=null;
        for (int i = 0; i < units.size(); i++) {
            Unit currUnit = units.get(i);
            String unitCode = currUnit.getUnitCode();

             if (unit1Code.equals(unitCode)) {
              selectedUnit = currUnit;

            } 
        }
        return selectedUnit;
    }
```